# Android Call Recording app - In Call Recorder AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION not recording call from both side

Tags: android, call-recording, audio-source

I am trying to record call through my android app.
I am using

```
 MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION
 MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB - encoding
 MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB - ourputformat
```

as audio configuration.
On my galaxy s8+ it is only recording my side of voice instead of both .
I have tried VOICE_CALL, UPLINK , DOWNLINK but nothing works. I have very feeble other end voice by using audio source as MIC. Please help how to resolve this . Thanks in advance.